# How to initialize activeMQ broker with failover

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I need to send JMS messages to the following provider location:

```
failover:(tcp://amq.vip.ebay.com:61616,tcp://amqstby.vip.ebay.com:61616)?initialReconnectDelay=100&randomize=false&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0
```

How to correctly initialize ConnectorFactory for it? Should I just do the follwing?

```
String url = "failover:(tcp://amq.vip.ebay.com:61616,tcp://amqstby.vip.ebay.com:61616)?initialReconnectDelay=100&randomize=false&wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0"; 
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
```

Or the things are more tricky with this kind of provider urls?

Answer (score 2):

That is the correct syntax.  Be careful when turning off the inactivity monitor.

Comment: Replying to quite an old thread, but would the URLs be hard-coded in the code? How do we get the Master URL dynamically especially if the ActiveMQ cluster is in cloud or running within a Docker container?